# First statement in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data in the given way below

```
ID    typ    date 
1     A      2014jan01
1     B      2014mar01
1     B      2014apr01
1     A      2014jun01
```

I want to create a new variable with Count, wrt the typ and also date. 
DESIRED OUTPUT

```
ID    typ    date          count
1     A      2014jan01       1
1     B      2014mar01       1
1     B      2014apr01       2
1     A      2014jun01       1
```

i wrote this program

```
proc sort data=have; by ID date typ;run;
data want;
set have;
by ID date typ;
if first.typ then Count=1;
else 
Count+1; run;
```

but it is not giving the desired result.

Comment: You need to use a retain statement so count is retained on subsequent rows. Examples here:http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214163.htm

Comment: you mean data want; set have; retain Count; by ID date typ;........ run; like this?

Comment: I tried but it gave me a continuous Count on the basis if ID

Comment: You already have an implied retain from the Count+1 statement.  I'm confused by your logic / desired result.  Why does your third record show count=2?  When you set by ID typ date it will show count=1.  If you changed to sort by ID typ date and set by ID TYP it would show count=2, but then the fourth record would also show count=2.

Comment: @Quentin the basic idea is to have the ID and typ on ascending date, so I want to give a Count on the continuous typ based on the ascending date. that is whay my desired output shows that way. I give the code like this. `code`proc sort data=have;by ID date typ; and then Data want;set have; by ID date typ; retain count;if first.typ then Count=1 ;else Count+1; run this give me all 1's. how do I get to the desired output? what is wrong in my statement?

Comment: Yes, would expect all 1's from the code. Still confused as to your logic.  Why do you have count=2 for the fourth record?  It's because after you have sorted by ID date typ, there are two consecutive records with same values for ID and typ?  I haven't used it, you could try by ID type / notsorted ;  on the datastep and see if that helps.  Or I might try using lag()

Comment: Are you asking to count the number of consecutive records (by id/date) with the same `typ`?

Answer (score 0):

@Quentin has provided the correct answer (using the NOTSORTED option in the data step).  You need to understand how the FIRST variable works with the order of variables in the BY statement. Your order is ID DATE TYP, so FIRST.ID is set to 1 for the first record only, FIRST.DATE is set to 1 for all records as the date is different each time, which means that any subsequent variable (i.e. FIRST.TYP) is also set to 1 for all records. Below is the code you should be running (credit to @Quentin)

```
proc sort data=have; by ID date typ;run;
data want;
set have;
by ID typ date notsorted;
if first.typ then Count=1;
else Count+1; 
run;
```

Comment: You also need a `notsorted` on `typ`, i.e. `by ID typ notsorted date notsorted`.

Comment: notsorted applies to the whole BY statement, so it's only needed the once.  What I could have done however is omit DATE from the BY statement as it's not necessary for this purpose.

Comment: ya @Quentin i tired notsorted and it worked.. Amazing.. thank you